# Linear programming with power pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, linear-programming, dax

I need to make a best case scenario analysis in a spreadhseet heavily built over Power Pivot.

So I was wondering if it would be possible to make a linear optimization within PP.

The problem is as follows:

I have N carriers, each one with a price per travel and a capacity (travels/week). I need to minimize the cost ($/week) by distributing the X travels across these carriers.

Actually, I don't need to know **how** to distribute it, just the **minimum cost**

Example:

Carrier |   Price    | Capacity

A         $20           10

B         $30           20

C         $15           5

For X = 20, the information I need is just that the best case scenario would cost $425 (5*$15 + 10*$20 + 5*$30).

I couldn't figure out how to make the iterations, except for faking them by using multiple calculated columns

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "within PP" but Excel's Solver add-in can handle the linear programming and if there is no built-in interface, VBA can interface between the solver and powerpivot.

Comment: By "within PP" I mean through DAX and data relations, etc. I'm well aware that Solver is a great tool for linear programming, but the problem I described is for one route, and I have approximately 600 of them... And since this this is not the final analysis, it would be nice to be able to manipulate the results with power pivot.

Comment: DAX doesn't seem to be a full-fledged programming language at all, so I wouldn't think you could implement simplex on it.

Comment: Could you not better let the LP solver operate directly on the underlying database?

Comment: Seconding the other commenters. Your problem seems to be a knapsack problem, and DAX is certainly not designed to solve knapsack problems. Excel's solver won't work for 600 carriers due to size limitations. It is easy to roll out a solution yourself, or make use of existing implementations (e.g., [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwje5Orvr__MAhVHDxoKHXOQDJgQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.stanford.edu%2F~ashishg%2Fmsande111%2Fexcel%2Fsolver_tutorial_solutions.xls&usg=AFQjCNH2J5wa4kWsucCqJi_ScPLeADCY0Q)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cummulative total problem. Let's assume that the value for X is stored as a column on the same power pivot entity. We will call X TotalPeople.
Add a calculated column called CummulativeCapacity:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Capacity] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[Price] <= EARLIER ( Table1[Price] ) )
)
```

Then add another column to store the total price for the carrier:

```
    =
IF (
    [TotalPeople] > [CummulativeCapacity],
    [Price] * [Capacity],
    IF (
        (
            [TotalPeople]
                - CALCULATE (
                    MAX ( [CummulativeCapacity] ),
                    FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Price] < EARLIER ( Table1[Price] ) )
                )
        )
            * [Price]
            < 0,
        0,
        [TotalPeople]
            - CALCULATE (
                MAX ( [CummulativeCapacity] ),
                FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Price] < EARLIER ( Table1[Price] ) )
            )
    )
        * [Price]
)
```

The sum of total price will be the minimum cost.

Comment: Wow, you totally nailed it! With the proper adaptations I got exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot! I think it'd take quite a lot more experience with DAX for me to get to this result

Comment: Thanks @VituTomaz It's not as complex as it might look. The only important concept to grasp here is what EARLIER means.